# FlowableProcessor rsocket-js typescript

Tags: typescript, rsocket, rsocket-js

I'm trying to built a chat frontend with rsocket-websocket-client. I'm able to send message from frontend using `requestChannel(new Flowable(source...))` and receive message using `requestChannel(new Flowable.just({metatdata}))`.

I was trying to use `FlowableProcessor` to reduce two invocations of `requestChannel` into one.

Couldn't find documentation on `FlowableProcessor` for rsocket.

Here is my attempt:

```
const processor = new FlowableProcessor(
    new Flowable(source => {
        source.onSubscribe({
            cancel: () => {},
            request: n => {}
        });
        source.onNext({
            metadata: constructMetadataWithChannelId(channelId),
        });
    })
);
sock.requestChannel(processor.map(item => item))
    .subscribe({
        onComplete: () => {
            console.log(
                `complted subscribe`,
            );
        },
        onError: error1 => {
            console.log(
                `subscriber err: ${error1}`,
            );
        },
        onSubscribe: subscription => {
            console.log(
                `onSubscribe`,
            );
            setConnectStatus('connected');
            setChannelIdDone(true);
            subscription.request(1000);
        },
        onNext: (val: any) => {
            const value = JSON.parse(val) as Message;
            console.log(
                `received event from channel: ${JSON.stringify(
                                            value,
                                        )}`,
            );
        }
    })
```

I understand it's type issue. Not able to figure out where `processor.map(item => item)` is erroring out.

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'IPublisher<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Flowable<Payload<Buffer, Buffer>>'.
Type 'IPublisher<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'Flowable<Payload<Buffer, Buffer>>': lift, take
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is trivial. `FlawableProcessor` cannot be used cause it does not implement the same interface as `Flawable`.

At the moment `rsocket-js` is not well polished and has some flaws. Some of such flaws is inconsistent type usage. AFAIU it's supposed `IPublisher` and `ISubscriber` interfaces should be used in all other public interfaces. But for writer's simplicity (I guess) they're replaced with `Flowable` and `Single` types.

According to the source code `FlowableProcessor` does not extend `Flowable` but rather implements `IPublisher`, `ISubscriber` and `ISubscription` interfaces itself and does not implement `lift` and `take` methods implemented by `Flowable`. So it cannot be used directly instead of `Flowable` although it's supposed to be used as `IPublisher`.

In your sample I see no reason to use `FlowableProcessor`. Instead you can pass `Flowable` used as an argument for constructing `FlowableProcessor` to `requestChannel` method directly:

```
const requestSource = new Flowable(source => {
    source.onSubscribe({
        cancel: () => {},
        request: n => {}
    });
    source.onNext({
        metadata: constructMetadataWithChannelId(channelId),
    });
});
sock.requestChannel(requestSource.map(item => item))
    ...
```

If you really-really need to use `FlowableProcessor` processor in this piece of code then you can force cast it to `Flowable` but it can be source of unexpected error in future:

```
sock.requestChannel(processor.map(item => item) as any as Flowable)
```

Please, also note you use `Flowable` incorrectly. You send data upon subscription when data was not requested yet. This violates RSocket contract. The proper implementation should be something like:

```
    let requestsSink: {
        sendRequest(myRequest: unknown): void,
        complete(): void
    };
    const requestsSource = new Flowable((requestsSubscriber) => {
        // Number of the requests requested by subscriber.
        let requestedRequests = 0;
        // Buffer for requests which should be sent but not requested yet.
        const pendingRequests: unknown[] = [];
        let completed = false;

        requestsSink = {
            sendRequest(myRequest: unknown) {
                if (completed) {
                    // It's completed, nobody expects this request.
                    return;
                }
                if (requestedRequests > 0) {
                    --requestedRequests;
                    requestsSubscriber.onNext(myRequest);
                } else {
                    pendingRequests.push(myRequest);
                }
            },
            complete() {
                if (!completed) {
                    completed = true;
                    requestsSubscriber.onComplete();
                }
            },
        };

        requestsSubscriber.onSubscribe({
            cancel: () => {
                // TODO: Should be handled somehow.
            },
            request(n: number) {
                const toSend = pendingRequests.splice(n);
                requestedRequests += n - toSend.length;
                for (const pending of toSend) {
                    requestsSubscriber.onNext(pending);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    sock.requestChannel(requestsSource.map(item => item))
        ...
    
    // Somewhere else the data is provided:
    if (requestsSink != null) {
        requestsSink.sendRequest({});
        requestsSink.sendRequest({});
        requestsSink.sendRequest({});
        requestsSink.sendRequest({});
        requestsSink.complete();
    }
```